# How to render rotating propeller?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, blur

I have a nice (in my opinion :) ) looking propeller on my Fokker VII. I am happy with this for stationary shots, but if I want to composite this in an aerial scene, I obviously shouldn't have the propeller still.

[image: propeller]

How would you render this propeller in a way that it looks like it is spinning very fast? What are the tricks, do you blur it or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you mean the motion blur effect.

In **Cycles** render engine, you can first animate the propeller with a very fast rotation, and toggle **Motion Blur** in Render tab, then set a appropriate Shutter time:

[image]

For **Blender Internal** render engine, there is also a **Sampled Motion Blur** panel in the Render tab:

[image]

For compositing, you can enable **Vector** pass in Render Layers tab, and use **Vector Blur** node to make use of it. Example:

[image]

Comment: Is this 3d motion blur or a hack in from the compositor?

Comment: @Vader - no, though you can do that too if you want (using a vector pass)

Comment: I'm just about to update the vector way. :)

Comment: okay, no need for me to do it than :D

Comment: why do we need Z for the vector pass?

Comment: It needs Z pass to determine by how far the moving pixel can be against the camera. For example, you can imagine a car shuttling right in front of your face, and a train running 1km far from you. Even they got same speed, I'm sure you can tell which one should be blurred more. :)

Comment: However, that Vector blur method sometimes got unwanted results, e.g. in this case, you can see the difference from the first two ways.